# Растянуть элемент по ширине корневого

Tags: css, css3

Корневой элемент имеет определенную ширину (растянут не во весь `body`). Внутри него есть блок типа `container` в `Bootstrap`. Можно ли как-то на `css` растянуть элемент (в примере - `this`) по ширине корневого, чтобы он не прилегал к границам экрана?

```
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="this">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.a {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}

.b {
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px dashed green;
}

.this {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

https://codepen.io/photosho/pen/jOpXWoy

Answer (score 1):

Вроде так

```css
:root {
  --bs-cont: 500px;
  --bs-inner: 300px;
  --bs-width-float: calc(var(--bs-cont) - var(--bs-inner));
  --bs-width-inner-float: calc(var(--bs-inner) + var(--bs-width-float));
}

.a {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: var(--bs-cont);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
}

.b {
  width: var(--bs-inner);
  margin: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px dashed green;
}

.this {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: calc(var(--bs-width-inner-float) - 30px);
  transform: translate(calc(0px - (var(--bs-width-float) / 2)), 0);
}
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="this">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Нет, элемент `this` должен быть растянут по ширине `a`. Но не через `position: absolute`. Я сам не нашел способа, но предположил, что могу ошибаться.

Comment: Всё он растянут

Comment: Как вариант. Спасибо.